# Get Parameters Problems in Yii2

Tags: php, web, yii2, yii-url-manager

My question is that i will have the `?` at the beginning of the get parameter's name.For example,
if the url is

```
https://example.com/path?id=2
```

I will get a get parameter named `?id`.How can I get the `id` without `?` instead of using such way:

```
https://example.com/path?&id=2
```

It's wired : )

---------------- Here is details ----------------

The url manager config:

```php
[
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl'   => true,
        'showScriptName'    => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'pattern'   => '<lang:(zh|en)>/login',
                'route'     => 'account/default/login',
            ],
            [
                'pattern'   => '<lang:(zh|en|api)>/<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
                'route'     => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
                'defaults'  => [
                    'lang'      => 'zh',
                    'modules'   => 'dashboard',
                    'controller'=> 'default',
                    'action'    => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

You see, I will use the `lang` parameter to control the language version of the website.And I found Yii will handle the `lang` as a get parameter.So that's the problem.`lang` might be the first get parameter, so the php handle the the `?` as the part of the parameter's name.

if I print the get parameters, I will get this.

```
https://example.com/en/modules/controller/action?id=1
```

The code goes:

```php
var_dump(\Yii::$app->request->get());
```

It will print:

```
array(2) { ["lang"]=> string(3) "en" ["?id"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

THX A LOT.

Comment: Can you include your `.htaccess`? It looks like the url is being rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

#### Include the `ID` parameter in the pattern that you are matching against.

```
[
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl'   => true,
        'showScriptName'    => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'pattern'   => '<lang:(zh|en)>/login',
                'route'     => 'account/default/login',
            ],
            [
                // Add the id to the pattern in the following line
                'pattern'   => '<lang:(zh|en|api)>/<modules>/<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>',
                'route'     => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
                'defaults'  => [
                    'lang'      => 'zh',
                    'modules'   => 'dashboard',
                    'controller'=> 'default',
                    'action'    => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Changing the `pattern` element to the following:

```
'pattern' => '<lang:(zh|en|api)>/<modules>/<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>',
```

Will capture a digit after a slash and make it available to your action as the `$id` method parameter.

If you wanted to use a question mark, instead of a slash, to separate the action from the parameter, I *guess* you could use this pattern:

```
'pattern' => '<lang:(zh|en|api)>/<modules>/<controller>/<action>?<id:\d+>'
```

But I have not tried it.

Comment: Thx for ur answer. Here `id` is just an example. The main problem here is `?` will add to the first parameter's name.If I use `https://example.com/path?&id=1` and I will get correct parameter.But if I reload the page, the chrome will delete the empty parameter, and it will cause an error : (. The php will get `?id` instead of `id`.

Comment: That makes sense, it just seems like having the first parameter defined, and at the beginning of the url, and not defining the second one, is confusing the `UrlManager`, if you define the second parameter in the pattern, the url generated will be `https://example.com/zh/controller/action/1` without the `?` or `&` tokens, and then you will receive the `id` or whichever name you use, parameter, did you try it yet?

Comment: I've tried, but i'm afraid it may not satisfy my request. Some api requires `id` param but others may not.While others may request more than one param, so at least there is one `?` included in one param's name. My solution now is including one meaningless get param after the `?` as the 1st param (the 2nd in Yii) : (.